# anything to discuss or something to discuss

Tags: grammar

I am trying to create the following sentence:

> Please call me if there will be something to discuss

But it sounds like I am not really interested in the other's person opinion. I was thinking about replacing **"something"** with **"anything"**, so that it would be more clear that I do really wanna hear from that person.

Is there any difference between these two?
What are your feelings about it?

Comment: It's *if there **is** something / anything to discuss*, not ***will be***.

Comment: "Please call me, if there **is** anything to discuss...", "...If you **have** anything to discuss...",  "...should you have anything to discuss...", "in case you **have** anything to discuss, please call me...

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps they don't want to be disturbed if there only *might* be something to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not totally grammatically correct: it should be like:- Please call me if there is anything to discuss.
"Something" implies that the thing has to be discussable and "anything" implies that it could be literally anything.
Hope it helped. 
Thank You

Comment: What is really wrong is "if there will be".  Both something and anything may fit depending on context.